# Read specific bytes from RandomAccessFile using FileChannel : Java

Tags: java, buffer, nio, bytebuffer, filechannel

I have a RandomAccessFile and its FileChannel. What I'm trying to do is read a specific section of the bytes from said file; however, while looking over the FileChannel read methods, I didn't see overloads that would help with what I'm trying to do, only methods which would read the entire content, or read content to a specific position in the buffer that the read method takes in. Is there a method that I'm missing that will help me accomplish my goal of reading a specific chunk of bytes, or will I need to read in the entire channel into the buffer and then parse out the section somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to a specific position in the file using [`FileChannel#position(long)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#position%28long%29) and then [`read`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#read%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29) a buffer in the desired size.

Comment: Which read are you referring to? I don't see any overloaded reads that specify the buffer size.

Comment: @ChrisV. Create the ByteBuffer of the size required. Or else just use RandomAccessFile.read(buffer,int,int), unless you have a strong reason for using a channel.